# Selenium print html code in a given xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium and I want to print the HTML code in a given Xpath were there is no text, this is the code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
    driver.get("link")
    code=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[2]/article/div/div/div[1]/div[1]')

    print("HTML code:\n", code)
```

But it returns this:

```
    <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8f119595825f509ba283758a8f2c754d", element="d2d5b697-253c-4ee9-99c0-7075adc28a1a")>
```

Comment: Do you want the value that's inside the html or the whole div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are trying to print the html code of a given `webelement`. In order to do that, you can access the `outerHTML` attribute of the element. Here is how you do it:

```
code = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[2]/article/div/div/div[1]/div[1]').get_attribute('outerHTML')

print("HTML code:\n",code)
```

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("link")
time.sleep(3)

code = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[2]/article/div/div/div[1]/div[1]').get_attribute('outerHTML')

print("HTML code:\n",code)

driver.close()
```

I tried the same with google's `I'm Feeling Lucky` button, just to check whether my code works. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
time.sleep(3)

code = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[2]').get_attribute('outerHTML')

print("HTML code:\n",code)

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
HTML code:
 <input class="RNmpXc" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" aria-label="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="btnI" type="submit" jsaction="sf.lck" data-ved="0ahUKEwiFpYWc4uHsAhVy63MBHY3fBdMQ19QECAw">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you need the inner text

```py
print(code.text)
```

This should work if you want the value

```py
print(code.get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: I've already tried it but since the code doesn't contain any text it returns nothing. Thank you anyway.